# How does magenta evaluate the melodies it generates

Tags: tensorflow, evaluation, magenta

When I trained magenta melody_rnn model and did the evaluation, I got 4 info:

1. Global Step. I know it represents the number of epochs the model was trained
2. Loss
3. Perplexity
4. Accuracy

I'm curious how they were computed? Are there any documents introducing these?